# Divide floating point with intager

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, floating-point, integer

So, I'm trying to divide values across two columns of a .csv file, one of which comprises intagers ('counts'), and the other is made up of floats ('Surface').

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'G:\file_path\file1.csv')

df['f'] = df['counts']/df['Surface']
```

Doing so returns the 'TypeError: string indices must be integers' error message.

An example of the file is:

[image: df.head()]

I have tried to find information online on how to divide floats but can only find endless resourcess on how to use the one-slash (/) or two-slash (//) methods to output floats or intagers, opposed to anything about actually dividing floats themselves.

Any ideas on how I resolve this?? Surely it can't be all that complicated.

Cheers,
R

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example? Currently without knowing what `df` contains it is difficult to help. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @ScootCork I have added the additional info to the original post for you

Comment: Don't directly see an issue, could you add the full stack trace?

Comment: Same here, dont understand where I've gone wrong. Stack trace? Sorry I'm unfamiliar with this term. My entire script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect one of the columns is dtype object.

Please try

Data

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'counts':[49, 47,44,43],'Surface':[1.878914,1.854631,1.854631,1.660323]})
print(df)


counts   Surface
0      49  1.878914
1      47  1.854631
2      44  1.854631
3      43  1.660323
   

  df['f'] = df['counts'].astype(int)/df['Surface'].astype(float)



 counts   Surface          f
0      49  1.878914  26.078895
1      47  1.854631  25.341968
2      44  1.854631  23.724396
3      43  1.660323  25.898575
```

Comment: This did not work, pulls up the same error message: 'TypeError: string indices must be integers'. I have added some additional info to the original question to help resolve

Comment: Happy I was of help. Keep coding